# How to find x,y,z values given the index in a linear 3D array?

Tags: arrays, 3d

Given a 3D space of (10, 10, 10) specified in a linear array:

```
[10x10x10]
```

Instead of

```
[10][10][10]
```

I understand how to get an index of [x][y][z] by doing the following:

```
[x + (y * W) ) + ( z * W * H )]
```

Or

```
[x + (y * 10) ) + ( z * 10 * 10 )]
```

How do I go in reverse? If I have the index `[i]` how do I go about finding `(x,y,z)`?

Answer (score 1):

For every `x`, there are 10 elements of `y`.  For every `y`, there are 10 elements of `z`.  In this sense, `z` is a sort of iterator that gives the smallest increments in your array.  Every time `z` increments 10*10 times, `x` increments once:

```
//x = i/(dim(y)*dim(z)) % dim(x)
x = i/(10*10) % 10 //integer division
```

Similarly for `y`, however `z` only needs to increment 10 times for `y` to increment.

```
//y = i/dim(z) % dim(y)
y = i/(10) % 10 //integer division
```

Finally, `z` always increments whenever `z` increments (that sounded stupid, but I was trying to follow my process from the other two.  What I'm trying to say is that `z` will always increment when the iterator increments).

```
//z = i % dim(z)
z = i % 10
```

Edit: `dim()` is supposed to return the size of the specified dimension.  It is poorly named in this example and I apologize for that.

Answer (score 0):

I use some function overloading to support 2d and 3d the math is similar to 2d but with the height to figure out the `Z` axis.

```
fromPos(x: number, y: number, z: number, width: number, height: number): number
fromPos(x: number, y: number, width: number): number
fromPos(x: number, y: number, zOrWidth: number, width?: number , height?: number): number {
    if(width != undefined && height != undefined) {
        let z = zOrWidth;
        return (x + width * y) + (z * width * height)
    } else {
        return x + zOrWidth * y;
    }
}

fromIndex (index: number, width: number, height: number): Vector3
fromIndex (index: number, width: number): Vector2
fromIndex (index: number, width: number, height?: number): Vector2 {
    if(height != undefined) {
        return {
            x: index % width,
            y: Math.floor(index / width % height),
            z: Math.floor(index / ( width * height ))
        } as Vector3;
    } else {
        return {
            x: index % width,
            y: index / width
        } as Vector2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use integer division `/` and the modulus function `%` in the following algorithm (C-style code)

```
// find indexes `i`,`j`,`k` from the flat index `q`
// dimensions n,m,l (i=0..n-1, j=0..m-1, k=0..l-1)
// memory is layout is last index `i` changing fastest
// q = i + n*( j + m*k )

i = q % n;  
q = q / n;
j = q % m; 
i = q / m;
```

Example per question posted

The elements at `(7,3,5)` has index `q = 7+10*(3+10*5) = 537`

```
i = 537 % 10 = 7
537 / 10 = 53
j =  53 % 10 = 3
k =  53 / 10 = 5
```

So `(i,j,k)=(7,3,5)`.